# Item in DropDownList

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms

In a winform I have a DDL that is connected to a field in a MySQL database.
In it there is a list of items that the user must select one, and then click OK to confirm and exit.
Here's okay.
However, if the user opens this form, I wish to appear in the DDL selected item previously.
Will you give me a hand please? thanks

```
Com.CommandText = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ..."; 

reader = Com.ExecuteReader(); 
while (reader.Read()) 
{
    testo1.Text= reader["richieste_1"].ToString(); // it's OK 
}  
//CmbCausa1.SelectedText = reader["causeID_1"].ToString(); // NOK  
//CmbCausa1.Items.Add(reader["causeID_1"].ToString()); NOK -->
```

Comment: can you add some code you have tried already ? Its a bit vague ..

Comment: So you want the DDL to remember was was last selected when a user re-opens the form?

Comment: Before closing the form, you must save the last selected item and the current user to the database. This you, you can retrieve that when the form is opened again

Comment: yes, I would like that the DDL "remember" the last previous selected. The code that I use is this: <!--Com.CommandText = "SELECT ... FROM " ...
WHERE ...
reader = Com.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{testo1.Text= reader["richieste_1"].ToString(); // it's OK
//CmbCausa1.SelectedText = reader["causeID_1"].ToString(); // NOK
CmbCausa1.Items.Add(reader["causeID_1"].ToString()); NOK -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following for your ComboBox:

```
var selected = reader["causeID_1"].ToString();
...
var index = CmbCausa1.FindString(selected);
CmbCausa1.SelectedIndex = index;
```

More about the FindString method can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxyt1t12.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your application is an install, you can have a settings file in the install folder.

If it's not, you can save that value in the database, since the application uses a database already.

There is also the option of the [applications settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx), which will allow you to save that information. This option, I feel, is best.